# Cannot select multiple items in Listbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, listbox

I have a `ListBox` and `DropDownList` in `GridView` `EditItemTemplate`. 
On `rowEditing`, I want to select all the items in `ListBox`.
Below is my code:

```
string categories = (e.Row.FindControl("lblCategoryID") as Label).Text;          
ListBox lbx = (ListBox)e.Row.FindControl("lbSelectedCategory");
DropDownList drp = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("drpCat");
List<string> TagIds = categories.Split(',').ToList();
lbx.SelectionMode = ListSelectionMode.Multiple;
foreach (string s in TagIds)
{
     ListItem li = drp.Items.FindByValue(s);
     lbx.Items.Add(li);
}
```

Here the items gets added into the `Listbox`.

But when I try to select the multiple items,

```
for (int i = 0; i < lbx.Items.Count; i++)
{
     lbx.Items[i].Selected = true;
}
```

I get error :

> cannot select multiple items in a  dropdownlist.

Aspx:

```
<EditItemTemplate>
   <asp:Label ID="lblCategoryID" Text='<%# Bind("tag_id") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
   <asp:ListBox ID="lbSelectedCategory" Visible="false" Width="150px" runat="server"
         SelectionMode="Multiple" CssClass="chosen-select"></asp:ListBox>
   <asp:DropDownList ID="drpCat" AutoPostBack="true"
         OnSelectedIndexChanged="drpCat_SelectedIndexChanged" CssClass="chosen-select" runat="server">
   </asp:DropDownList>
</EditItemTemplate>
```

Can anyone help me solving this Issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of finding the rows in the drop down and adding the same rows to the ListBox, try creating a new ListItem with the same value as the ListItem from the drop down and add that instead.

Comment: There is no ListboxItem, only Listitem. Anything else can be done? Thanks for the reply

Comment: I can select a  select a  single item. But not  multiple.

Comment: @shanna ok try using ListItems, but create a new one opposed to adding the one you find from the drop down directly.

Comment: @shanna great! Edited my answer to fit this solution